# Can I set offset position on Storyboard?

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, storyboard

Can I write like the code below on Storyboard?

```
let button = UIButton()
button.titleLabel.center = CGPoint(x:button.titleLabel.center.x, y:button.titleLabel.center.y + 30)
```

Comment: Well, you did, try and compile it and execute it. If it's not working the way you desire please post a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `UIEdgeInsets` and the UIButton property `titleEdgeInsets`.

```
button.titleLabelInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 30)
```

Depending on your exact needs and code, this should do what you need. (FYI - there is a `imageEdgeInsets` also.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is just what I wanted. I didn't know this property. Thanks.